# Iterate over linked list with conditional node links

Tags: python, linked-list

I am very new to the idea of coding so I'm not 100% sure what I'm asking. I have a Object list that has the ID of a box, The amount of selectable options and the ID's of the boxes its linked to.

I'm trying iterate in order across these boxes adding up all the possible options that can be selected
[image]

For example "Connect 6" would have a total of 3, "contect 7" a total of 2 and, "Connect 4" a total of 7

I have 2 classes 1 that sets up all the links in a list and 1 that then should iterate across them. I haven't been able to get to the sum part yet as whatever I make prints out the fist box ID forever till it crashes VS (No idea how to stop it doing my dumb shit once its started going, even closing the terminal doesn't help)

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, box_id):
        self.box_id = box_id
        self.options_number = None
        self.pre = None
        self.next = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.box_id

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.head = None
        self.reg_num = 0
        if nodes is not None:
            for node in nodes:
                box_id = node.box_id
                # print(f'One: {box_id}')
                # box_id = node.next
                # print(f'Two: {box_id}')
                # if box_id == []:
                #     print("I should really stop")
                while box_id != []:
                    print(box_id)
                    box_id = node.next
```

Here is what it looks like printing out the node.

```py
nodes = node_setup(test)
for node in nodes:
   print(f'Question Text: {node.name}  Current: {node.box_id} Options: {node.options_number} Next Link: {node.next}')
```

```
Question Text: Connect 1  Current: {30706B51-789C-4AFA-998D-759297B95F99} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
Question Text: Connect 2  Current: {EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA} Options: 3 Next Link: ['{77AC8029-95D8-4DA8-9B62-D487DBA742D6}']
Question Text: Connect 3  Current: {77AC8029-95D8-4DA8-9B62-D487DBA742D6} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{DF56E1B2-DD19-485D-B720-A5A28AA6C156}']
Question Text: Connect 5  Current: {B4045D8D-6E54-4E43-B820-4C70036F08AF} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{D1720CEC-81FF-4460-A5CB-86BC9B5AB7F5}']
Question Text: Connect 4  Current: {DF56E1B2-DD19-485D-B720-A5A28AA6C156} Options: 2 Next Link: ['{B4045D8D-6E54-4E43-B820-4C70036F08AF}', '{8C51E3B4-7302-4453-AEE0-7C9E659CA2B0}']
Question Text: Connect 6  Current: {8C51E3B4-7302-4453-AEE0-7C9E659CA2B0} Options: 2 Next Link: ['{D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06}']
Question Text: Connect 7  Current: {D1720CEC-81FF-4460-A5CB-86BC9B5AB7F5} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06}']
Question Text: Connect 8  Current: {D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06} Options: 1 Next Link: []
```

And here it is running LinkedList

```py
for node in nodes:
    print(f'Question Text: {node.name}  Current: {node.box_id} Options: {node.options_number} Next Link: {node.next}')
plz_Work = LinkedList(nodes)
```

```
Question Text: Connect 1  Current: {30706B51-789C-4AFA-998D-759297B95F99} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
Question Text: Connect 2  Current: {EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA} Options: 3 Next Link: ['{77AC8029-95D8-4DA8-9B62-D487DBA742D6}']
Question Text: Connect 3  Current: {77AC8029-95D8-4DA8-9B62-D487DBA742D6} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{DF56E1B2-DD19-485D-B720-A5A28AA6C156}']
Question Text: Connect 5  Current: {B4045D8D-6E54-4E43-B820-4C70036F08AF} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{D1720CEC-81FF-4460-A5CB-86BC9B5AB7F5}']
Question Text: Connect 4  Current: {DF56E1B2-DD19-485D-B720-A5A28AA6C156} Options: 2 Next Link: ['{B4045D8D-6E54-4E43-B820-4C70036F08AF}', '{8C51E3B4-7302-4453-AEE0-7C9E659CA2B0}']
Question Text: Connect 6  Current: {8C51E3B4-7302-4453-AEE0-7C9E659CA2B0} Options: 2 Next Link: ['{D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06}']
Question Text: Connect 7  Current: {D1720CEC-81FF-4460-A5CB-86BC9B5AB7F5} Options: 1 Next Link: ['{D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06}']
Question Text: Connect 8  Current: {D837ECDC-897D-4A91-89E3-F6222FE12F06} Options: 1 Next Link: []
['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
['{EA65B6DA-90FE-412A-AF1F-83F994CCB5FA}']
ect....
```

I'm honestly very very lost as to how to go about this, I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could give

Comment: Ctrl+C kills a running python script. For the infinite looping problem, use a debugger to step through your code. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: This does not look like a working linked list implementation -- I'd suggest starting with a basic linked list before doing anything more advanced with it!  This seems like a decent intro writeup to linked lists with Python: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/implementing-a-singly-linked-list-in-python/

Comment: The condition in `while node.name != []:`, and the assignment `node.name = node.next`, make no sense. Just think about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out now. I had the for in the wrong place.

Its still not perfect as I can't make it work where there are 2 links but for now this gets me past the forever loop to be able to work out the rest

```
class LinkedList():
def __init__(self, nodes=None):
    self.head = None
    self.reg_num = 0
    if nodes is not None:
        box_id = nodes[0].box_id
        while box_id != []:
            node_range = len(nodes)
            for node in range(node_range):
                if box_id == nodes[node].box_id:
                    name = nodes[node].name
                    print(f'name {name}')
                    next_id = nodes[node].next
                    if next_id != []:
                        next_id = next_id[0] #This needs to be something more clever
                    box_id = next_id
```

and prints

```
name Connect 1
name Connect 2
name Connect 3
name Connect 4
name Connect 5
name Connect 7
name Connect 8
```

===================================================

Edit: worked out how to do whole thing now

```
start_id = nodes[0].box_id
plz_Work = LinkedList(nodes, start_id)
```

class

```
class LinkedList():
def __init__(self, nodes, start_id):
    if nodes is not None:
        box_id = start_id
        while box_id != []:
            node_range = len(nodes)
            for node in range(node_range):
                if box_id == nodes[node].box_id:
                    name = nodes[node].name
                    print(f'name: {name}')
                    next_id = nodes[node].next
                    if next_id != []:
                        next_range = len(next_id)
                        if next_range < 2:
                            next_id = next_id[0]
                        else:
                            for next_num in range(next_range):
                                LinkedList(nodes, next_id[next_num])
                            next_id = []
                    box_id = next_id
```

Print

```
name: Connect 1
name: Connect 2
name: Connect 3
name: Connect 4
name: Connect 5
name: Connect 7
name: Connect 8
name: Connect 6
name: Connect 8
```